# Interpreting $ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | k x \rangle \langle k x | dx $ via the Riemann limit of a sum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Consider:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | x  \rangle  \langle x | dx = I$$

where $I$ is the identity. Usually I think of this in a riemannian limit of a sum sense with $\Delta x = 2k/N$:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | x  \rangle  \langle x | dx = (\dots + |0\rangle \langle 0 | + | \Delta x \rangle \langle \Delta x | + | 2 \Delta x \rangle \langle 2 \Delta x | + \dots) \Delta x$$

Or more precisely:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | x  \rangle  \langle x | dx = \lim_{k \to\infty} \lim_{ N  \to \infty} \sum_{i= 0}^{-N }|i \Delta x\rangle \langle i \Delta x| \Delta x + \sum_{j= 1}^{N }|j \Delta x\rangle \langle j \Delta x| \Delta x $$

Upon change of variables $x \to 2x$:

$$ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | 2x \rangle  \langle 2x | d2x = I $$

Now using the distributive property:

$$ 2 \int_{- \infty}^\infty | 2x  \rangle  \langle 2x | dx = I $$

If I again interpret this as done previously:

$$ I \stackrel{!}{=} 2 \lim_{k \to\infty} \lim_{ N \Delta x \to k} \sum_{i= 0}^{-N }| 2 i \Delta x\rangle \langle 2 i \Delta x| \Delta x + \sum_{j= 1}^{N }| 2 j \Delta  x \rangle \langle 2 j \Delta x| \Delta x $$

But I find this counter-intuitive that by a simple substitution. I lose half my bra and kets. I suspect the R.H.S is no longer the identity.

### Question

Obviously I'm going wrong somewhere. I suspect it is in my interpretation of Riemann limit of a sum of this operator. My question is there a way to interpret $ \int_{- \infty}^\infty | k x  \rangle  \langle k x | dx $ via the Riemann limit of a sum? If not, what is the proper way to understand it?

Comment: You do not lose half your bras and kets. The limit in front of the sum is not correct, it should be $\lim_{N\to\infty,~ \Delta x\to 0}$ with $N\Delta x = const$. So $\Delta x \propto 1/N$. Because of that, your substitution is incorrect. If you substitute $\Delta x' = \Delta x/2$, you also need to substitute $N' = 2N$ such that $\Delta x' N' = const$ remains the same. Then, the sum does not change. The kets remain the same because $2i \Delta x' = 2i \Delta x/2 = i\Delta x$.

Comment: But don't we always take this constant to be infinity? Like I mean, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx  = 2  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(2x) dx  $

Comment: Yes, but the Riemann integration limit comes before taking the integration to infinity. The Riemann limit has to be well defined for every finite $k$, then we can take $k\to \infty$. And for every finite $k$, the change of variables does not change the sum (as it should not).

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)